# How to install Infer.NET to Unity 2018.3

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine, infer.net

I have a fresh Unity project and following the instructions in [Using .NET 4.x in Unity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/cross-platform/unity-scripting-upgrade?view=vs-2019), i've downloaded Microsoft.ML.Probabilistic.Compiler NuGet package from the [gallery](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ML.Probabilistic.Compiler/) and copied the DLL to Assets/Plugins. After this Unity outputs an error message

> Assembly 'Assets/Plugins/Microsoft.ML.Probabilistic.Compiler.dll' will
>   not be loaded due to errors: Unable to resolve reference
>   'Microsoft.ML.Probabilistic'. Is the assembly missing or incompatible
>   with the current platform?

I downloaded and copied the missing DLL and every following missing DLL dependency

- Microsoft.ML.Probabilistic.dll
- System.CodeDom.dll
- Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.dll
- Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.dll
- System.Collections.Immutable.dll
- System.Reflection.Metadata.dll

Unity showed no more errors after adding the System.Reflection.Metadata.dll.

When i add

```
using Microsoft.ML.Probabilistic;
using Microsoft.ML.Probabilistic.Compiler;
```

to a script, the project builds fine in both Unity and Visual Studio Community, but when i attempt to use the libraries, namely the `Microsoft.ML.Probabilistic.Compiler.Variable<T>` class

```
using UnityEngine;
using Microsoft.ML.Probabilistic;
using Microsoft.ML.Probabilistic.Compiler;

public class Main : MonoBehaviour {
    void Start () {
        Variable<bool> firstCoin = Variable.Bernoulli (0.5);
    }
}
```

both Unity and Visual Studio fail with

> Assets/Scripts/Main.cs(7,3): error CS0246: The type or namespace name
>   'Variable<>' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or
>   an assembly reference?)

and

> Assets/Scripts/Main.cs(7,30): error CS0103: The name 'Variable' does
>   not exist in the current context

Adding `-r:Microsoft.ML.Probabilistic.Compiler.dll` to Assets/mcs.rsp file generates an error

> Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler version 2.9.1.65535 (9d34608e)
>   Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
>
> error CS0006: Metadata file 'Microsoft.ML.Probabilistic.Compiler.dll'
>   could not be found

The project configuration is

- Unity 2018.3.10f1
- Visual Studio for Mac Community
- Build Settings/Platform: iOS
- Player Settings/Scripting Runtime Version: .NET 4.x Equivalent

it makes no difference whether i set

- Player Settings/Api Compatibility Level: .NET
  4.x

or

- Player Settings/Api Compatibility Level: .NET Standard 2.0

Other settings are left to their defaults.

I haven't added the DLLs to the vs-project in Visual Studio as the guide says

> Visual Studio regenerates .csproj and .sln files for Unity projects
>   each time they're opened. As a result, you cannot add assembly
>   references directly in Visual Studio because they'll be lost upon
>   reopening the project. Instead, a special text file named mcs.rsp must
>   be used:
>
> Create a new text file named mcs.rsp in your Unity project's root Assets directory.
>
> On the first line in the empty text file, enter: -r:System.Net.Http.dll and then save the file. You can replace "System.Net.Http.dll" with any included assembly that might be missing a reference.
>
> Restart the Unity editor.

Comment: Is it added as a reference in the vs solution?

Comment: Nothing is done in Visual Studio. As the Microsoft guide says it would get overwritten and lost anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Variable<bool>` Isn't part of either `Probabilistic` or `Probabilistic.Compiler`

Instead you need to include `using Microsoft.ML.Probabilistic.Models;`, of which `Variable<T>` is part.

```
using UnityEngine;
using Microsoft.ML.Probabilistic.Models;//we need Probabilistic.Models

public class SomeScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start()
    {
        Variable<bool> firstCoin = Variable.Bernoulli(0.5);
    }
}
```

Tested this with unity 2018.3 and 2019.1, both with .net 4.x runtime, and it builds fine (Although on Windows, it shouldn't make a difference).

> ... and copied the DLL to Assets/Plugins. After this Unity outputs an error message

I personally didn't have to do this to get it to work. I downloaded the package from NuGet straight into the default directory (project/Packages/) using `Install-Package Microsoft.ML.Probabilistic.Compiler -Version 0.3.1810.501`. It also didn't require me to download any additional DLL's.

Comment: Yes, yes, that's it! Thank you so much! Unfortunately Infer.NET model builder doesn't work with IL2CPP AOT compiler on iOS. ATM i see this impossible. Nonetheless your answer solved the problem i thought i had with the installation and Infer.NET does work in the Unity editor.